# Custom notification system with laravel 5.2

Tags: jquery, css, laravel, notifications

I'm trying to create custom notification system with laravel 5.2, jquery, html and css.

Here is the html in blade where i'm expecting to display the notification.

```
<section class="notification">
    <div class="left-side">
       <i class="icon ion-ios-information-outline"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="right-side">
       {{ Session::get('nofitication_message')}}
       <a href="" class="pull-right close_notification">
          <i class="icon ion-close-round"></i>
       </a>
    </div>
 </section>
```

The jquery function where i'm displaying the notification for only 5 seconds.

```
function shownotification()
{
    console.log('im called');

    $('.notification').addClass('show');

    setTimeout(function(){
        $('.notification').removeClass('show');
    }, 4000);

    $('.close_notification').onclick(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        $('.notification').removeClass('show');
    })
}
```

And lastly the session variable i'm sending from the controller

return redirect()->back()->with('nofitication_message', 'Your message has been sent!');

The issue now is:
1. How to retrieve that notification message from the session
2. How to call the function shownotification() from blade to display the notification

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can use jquery $( document ).ready() to call your shownotification() function on page load

Comment: Cool i did that but i still can't control the session message

Comment: What you need now ? You are not able to retrieve message from session ?

Comment: Yes, i dont know if sending the flash message by ->with('info', 'my message') is correct

Comment: yes it looks right. You can do one thing right this {{ var_dump(Session::all()) }} to check what your session contains

Comment: thanks a lot. the problem is resolved. the web middleware was blocking all session's flash messages. i had to remove it. now it is working as expected.